# Django delete S3 bucket on button click

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a list of S3 buckets on AWS. Each bucket's name is displayed and I'm trying to implement a delete button using django.
The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure yet how to get and pass bucket name variable to the delete function I have. Here's what I've done so far:

DeleteBucketView.py

```
class deleteBucket(TemplateView):
template_name = "project/delete_bucket.html"

def deleteBucket(self, name):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(name)
    bucket.delete()
```

S3.html

```
<div class="s3Items">
  {% for bucket in buckets %}
  <div class="s3Name">
    <div id="left">
      <a href="#"><h4 id='s3ItemName'>{{ bucket.bucketName }}</h4></a>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <ul id='s3ItemDesc'>
        <li>{{ bucket.createdAt }}</li>
          <li>{{ bucket.totalSize }}/4GB</li>
        <li>
          <form method="post" action="{% url 'project:deleteBucket' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" name="button" class='button delete'>Delete</button>
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

deletebucket.html is empty as I'm not sure what I could enter there.
I need to call function `deleteBucket` when I click delete button, however I would need to pass bucket's name to the function as well. I think I also need to define post in deleteBucket view but I'm not sure how to go from there.
How do I pass the bucket's name into the function and make this work? Do I need to add anything in deleteBucket.html?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about your url definition but I assume like this...

```
url(r'^delete-bucket/(?P<name>\w+)$', 'views.deleteBucket.as_view()', name='delete_bucket'),
```

And modify your view like this...

```
class deleteBucket(TemplateView):
    template_name = "project/delete_bucket.html"

    def delete_operation(self, name):
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        bucket = s3.Bucket(name)
        bucket.delete()

    def post(self, request, name):
        self.delete_operation(name)
        ...
```

And in the html you have to tell the name

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'project.delete_bucket' name=bucket.bucketNmae %}">
```

Comment: How do I call the function though?

Comment: Yes, now I have a proper link with the url variable pointing to the proper bucket name but my deleteBucket.html is empty. How can I call the functions and where should I call it?

Comment: Can you tell me what is deleteBucket.html ? And why is empty? I thought your class template is `template_name = "project/delete_bucket.html"`

Comment: Apologies, it's project/delete_bucket.html. What should I enter in it then? Also, now I'm getting an error `post() got multiple values for argument 'name'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160350/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-davidb).